# root doesn't see a FUSE mounted directory

Tags: linux, debian

I have a service on my debian machine that mounts google drive to directory `/home/myuser/gdrive`:

```
[Unit]
Description=FUSE filesystem over Google Drive
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=myuser
ExecStart=google-drive-ocamlfuse /home/myuser/gdrive
ExecStop=fusermount -u /home/myuser/gdrive
Restart=always
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also have a cron job that copies a directory from one folder to `gdrive`. The problem is that `root` user for some reason doesn't see `gdrive` directory.

```
sudo ls -la /home/myuser/
ls: cannot access '/home/myuser/gdrive': Permission denied
total 1700
...
d?????????  ? ?    ?          ?            ? gdrive
...
```

```
ls -la ~/
total 1704
...
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser  myuser     4096 Aug  2 09:24 gdrive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuse mounts are per user.

Fuse has a mount flag, `allow_other` that allows other users access to a fuse mounted filesystem.

Simply add `-o allow_other` to the mount command, so that it becomes

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse -o allow_other /home/myuser/gdrive
```

It's also possible to set it in `/etc/fuse.conf`.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I had to set ```user_allow_other``` in ```/etc/fuse.conf``` and then ```-o allow_other``` worked.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that network mounts are usually per-user, as each user may have access to different shares. Since you've set the mount process to run as `myuser`, that mount is probably only available to `myuser`. Have you considered running your `cron` job in the `myuser` context?

Comment: Not network file systems - it's [fuse specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the clarification.